# Joomla4: trigger a function from default.php button

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller, joomla

I have a button in my default.php. This button should reset my counter.

```
<input type="button" value="<?php echo 'reset' ?>" id="bnBack" onClick="<?php   $this->get('CountZero')?>" />
```

The function I created and want to call, is in model/CntModel.php

```
class CntModel extends BaseDatabaseModel
{

    public function getCountZero() 
    {
        $db = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->update('#__cnt')
        ->set('cnt = 0');
        $db->setQuery($query);
        $db->execute($query);
    }
}
```

I cannot access this function in default.php when I click my reset button.

How can I access this model method when I click my reset button in default.php?

I want to trigger the `getCountZero()`  when I click my reset button in the default.php view file.

Comment: Please ask your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.